# I want to take a string of numbers and turn each number into a text file title

Tags: batch-file, coding-style, numbers, pi

I was looking to turn a string of numbers (A million digits of Pi). Each number I would like to become a file name

For Example

3.14159

I would like 3 to be a text file name
. to be a text file name
1 to be a text file name
4 to be a text file name
1 to be a text file name
5 to be a text file name
9 to be a text file name
and etc etc etc.

I have searched the internet but nothing has come up.

If anyone would be able to help me with the code for that it would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by "a title of a text file" and what are you trying to achieve? If you mean a file name, then you're only going to have ten single-digit file names, and a file named `.` is not going to work on most OSes.

Comment: The two `1` text files are going to end up getting merged into the same file. I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Yes I do mean a file name.

Comment: @KenY-N - `.txt` is a perfectly valid file name in Windows.

Comment: Ok Next time I'll use .txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't get it what is your goal. I guess you want probably count the number of character in the string.

Thus this can help:

```
@echo off
if not exist pi-folder\nul md pi-folder
pushd pi-folder

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo 3.1234567890abc>"%tmp%\pi.tmp"
for %%l in ("%tmp%\pi.tmp") do set /a len=%%~zl
set /a len-=2
set /a count=len - 2
echo:
echo 3.1234567890abc count !count! characters after the dot
echo:

pause>nul
rem create one file per character
for /l %%i in (-1,-1,-%len%) do (
  for /f %%a in (%tmp%\pi.tmp) do (
    set char=%%a
    if "!char:~%%i,1!" neq "." (
      copy nul !char:~%%i,1!
    ) else (
      copy nul !char:~%%i,1!~
    )
  )
)
endlocal
popd
```

output:

```
3.1234567890abc count 13 characters after the dot

copy nul c
copy nul b
copy nul a
copy nul 0
copy nul 9
copy nul 8
copy nul 7
copy nul 6
copy nul 5
copy nul 4
copy nul 3
copy nul 2
copy nul 1
copy nul .~
copy nul 3
```

result after `dir /b`:

```
.~
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
a
b
c
```

Comment: I doubt, that this would work as intended with `A million digits of Pi`. On the other hand, I still haven't the slightest idea, what the actual goal could be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any sense in your request, but this does exactly what you want (and is much much quicker than to write a Million files, overwriting 999990 of them multiple times):

```
for /l %%i in (0,1,9) do break>%%i.txt
break>..txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed